# the moment i add .beforeEach guard on my vue-router the whole router stops to work

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vue-router4

Am developing on Laravel 9, Vue 3 and Vue-Router 4,

on front end routing works fine.... but once i add just a `beforeEach` guard. then the whole router stops to work

```
//this dont work
export const router = createRouter({
    routes,
    history : createWebHistory( import.meta.env.BASE_URL ),
    linkActiveClass : 'active'
}).beforeEach( (to, from) => {
    return true
})

//this works
 export const router = createRouter({
        routes,
        history : createWebHistory( import.meta.env.BASE_URL ),
        linkActiveClass : 'active'
    })
```

I need to be able to add guard on my router for the protected pages.
Below is my `packages.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.5.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "pinia": "^2.0.18",
        "vue": "^3.2.37",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `next()` instead of `return true`

```
export const router = createRouter({
    routes,
    history : createWebHistory( import.meta.env.BASE_URL ),
    linkActiveClass : 'active'
}).beforeEach( (to, from, next) => {
   next();
})
```

But , why are you invoking the beforeEach method if you are not adding any logic there? . `beforeEach` is supposed to be used when you have conditionals routes or you need to edit data before render the page.

Comment: in there i added logics to check if a user is logged in or not.... even ```next()``` dont work.
i've tried everything.... but my router just freezes there.... by just addition of that ```guard```

Comment: Here is an example from vue documentation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next